# Terraform aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration can't generate multiple rules with for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an S3 bucket with the following "folder" structure:

```
Bucket1----> /Partner1 ----> /Client1 ----> /User1
        |               |              |--> /User2
        |               |
        |               |--> /Client2 ----> /User1
        |
        |--> /Partner2 ----> /Client1 ----> /User1
```

and so on.

I'm trying to setup replication from this bucket to another such that a file placed in

`Bucket1/Partner1/client1/User1/`
should replicate to
`Bucket2/Partner1/client1/User1/`,

`Bucket1/Partner2/client1/User2/`
should replicate to
`Bucket2/Partner2/client1/User2/`,

and so on.

I'm trying to achieve this with the following terraform code:

```hcl
locals {
 s3_folders = [
  "Partner1/client1/User1",
  "Partner1/client1/User2",
  "Partner1/client1/User3",
  "Partner1/client1/User4",
  "Partner1/client1/User5",
  "Partner1/client2/User1",
  "Partner1/client3/User1",
  "Partner2/client1/User1",
  "Partner3/client1/User1"
 ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "replication" {
  for_each      = local.s3_input_folders

  depends_on    = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.source_bucket]
  role          = aws_iam_role.s3-replication-prod[0].arn
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.source_bucket.id

  rule {
    id = each.value

    filter {
      prefix =  each.value
    }

    status = "Enabled"

    destination {
      bucket        = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.app}-dev"
      storage_class = "ONEZONE_IA"

      access_control_translation {
        owner       = "Destination"
      }
      account = var.dev_account_id
    }

    delete_marker_replication {
        status = "Enabled"
    }
  }
}
```

This is not looping and creating 10 different rules, rather it overwrites the same rule on every run and I only get one rule as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "replication" {
  
  depends_on    = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.source_bucket]
  role          = aws_iam_role.s3-replication-prod[0].arn
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.source_bucket.id

  dynamic "rule" {
    
    for_each      = toset(local.s3_input_folders)
    
    content {
    
        id = rule.value

        filter {
            prefix =  rule.value
        }

        status = "Enabled"

        destination {
        bucket        = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.app}-dev"
        storage_class = "ONEZONE_IA"

        access_control_translation {
            owner       = "Destination"
        }
        account = var.dev_account_id
        }

        delete_marker_replication {
            status = "Enabled"
        }
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Marcin. The dynamic block construct you mentioned works to create the content blocks but it fails to apply because AWS needs multiple replication rules to be differentiated by priority. So some slight modifications achieve this:

```hcl
locals {
  s3_input_folders_list_counter = tolist([
    for i in range(length(local.s3_input_folders)) : i
  ])
  s3_input_folders_count_map = zipmap(local.s3_input_folders_list_counter, tolist(local.s3_input_folders))
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_replication_configuration" "replication" {
  depends_on    = [aws_s3_bucket_versioning.source_bucket]
  role          = aws_iam_role.s3-replication-prod[0].arn
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.source_bucket.id

   dynamic "rule" {
    
    for_each      = local.s3_input_folders_count_map
    
    content {
    
        id = rule.key
        priority = rule.key

        filter {
            prefix =  rule.value
        }

        status = "Enabled"

        destination {
        bucket        = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.app}-dev"
        storage_class = "ONEZONE_IA"

        access_control_translation {
            owner       = "Destination"
        }
        account = var.dev_account_id
        }

        delete_marker_replication {
            status = "Enabled"
        }
    }    
  }
}
```

which creates rules like these:

```hcl
+ rule {
          + id       = "0"
          + priority = 0
          + status   = "Enabled"

...
}
+ rule {
          + id       = "1"
          + priority = 1
          + status   = "Enabled"

...
}
```

and so on...